# Write text above other text

Tags: overlays, strikeout

What I would like to do is to make corrections to a document- to cross out some text using the ulem package and then to put the "correct" answer above it.

e.g.

```
\dotuline{\fontfamily{augie}\selectfont{nach den}} Türkei
```

yields a handwritten answer on a dotted line. Using `\usepackage{ulem}`, this can be struck out:

```
\dotuline{\sout{\fontfamily{augie}\selectfont{nach den}}} Türkei
```

but I would also like to put in the corrected answer above the text, preferably without having to go into math mode and using `\atop`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Four spaces of indent will format your code to look like code.  Also, is the answer "nach dem"?  My high school German is so rusty.

Answer (score 13):

can also be done with a simple tabular

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,calc}

\newcommand\strikeout[2][]{%
 \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}} 
    \makebox(0,0)[cb]{\textcolor{blue}{#1}} \\[-0.2\normalbaselineskip]
     \rlap{\color{red}\rule[0.5ex]{\widthof{#2}}{0.5pt}}#2
 \end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

Now is the the time for all good \strikeout[citizens]{men} to come to the aid of 
their \strikeout{their} country.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

You might be interested in the [`cancel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cancel) package.   Or something similar can be implemented in TikZ.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\strikeout}[2][]{%
    % usage: \strikeout[bar]{foo} strikes out foo and superimposes bar
    %        \strikeout{foo} strikes out foo.
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0]
        \node[anchor=base,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt] (main) {#2};
        \draw[red] ([yshift=0.5ex]main.base west) -- ([yshift=0.5ex]main.base east);
        \node[overlay,anchor=south,blue] at (main.north) (correction) {#1};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}

Now is the the time for all good \strikeout[citizens]{men} to come to the aid of their \strikeout{their} country.

\end{document}
```

[image: sample]

Comment: Thank you for the welcome and the suggestion! The correct answer should be just "nach" :-). The     cancel package helps me with a problem I didn't mention, in that it allows me to change the colour with which I strike things out, but it doesn't help me with writing in the correct answers above the ones that have been struck out. I've never used TikZ, but it looks a bit tricky! Is there nothing simpler? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: oops sorry just saw your code. Thankyou!!

Comment: @JTzara: Oh, I get it, the issue is not which case of article but whether an article is necessary at all.  You caught me between suggesting a method and coding it up.  Hope it helps.

Comment: How would you modify the above to get a bolder cross-out line (e.g. for use with larger font size)?  Could I use the "cancel" package in place of the "draw" command to get a diagonal slash through the text?  (Adding \cancel{#2} gives an error that the node must allow for a possibly empty argument).