# Put text on top of text that has strikethrough - like one would edit an essay

Tags: overlays, strikeout

I would like to obtain the same effect as in this question: [Write text above other text](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9276/write-text-above-other-text?rq=1)

But in those answers, it doesn't flow properly across multiple lines of text in the essay. If you strike too much out, the text runs off the page.

Comment: Is this of help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142242/robust-way-to-mark-draft-text/142258#142258

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.